# Not able to set header in angular 7 HttpClient with multipart/form-data

Tags: angular7

I have a service in which i am uploading a form data using FormData class.
In form i have several fields including one file. I have appended all the field in form data and using HttpClient's post method to upload the data.

```
saveMakerDetails(data:FormData){   
       return  this.http.post(`${env.base_url}/web/maker`,data,{headers:new HttpHeaders({"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"})});
    }
```

And below is my code to prepare FormData.

```
onSubmit(){
    let formData = new FormData();
    let data = {}
    for(let obj of Object.keys(this.profileForm.value)){
        if(obj == 'image'){
            formData.append("file",this.profileForm.value[obj]);
        } else {
            data[obj] = this.profileForm.value[obj];
        }
    }
    formData.append("maker",JSON.stringify(data));
    this.disableSave = true;
    this.adminService.saveMakerDetails(formData)
        .subscribe(res=>{
            this.disableSave = false;
        },err=>{
            this.disableSave = false;
        })

}
```

The problem is when i try to upload the server says the current request is not multipart.

I have tried setting various method for setting header in angular service but none of them seems working fine.

Here is my response

```
{timestamp: "2019-04-24T07:55:10.894+0000", status: 500, error: "Internal Server Error",…}
error: "Internal Server Error"
message: "Current request is not a multipart request"
path: "/v1/web/maker"
status: 500
timestamp: "2019-04-24T07:55:10.894+0000"}
```

It seems angular is not able to set Content-Type.
Below are the request header copied form browser.

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accessToken: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI1YzlhM2RhODRiODJjNjM5OTc0Y2QyNWIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTM4ODc5ODEsInN1YiI6ImNsaWVudCIsImlzcyI6ImlkZW1pYSJ9.r2Jh6PdXi3Ja8-UomFUJ7eGk2GXJhA4OqiYhQjcsFs8
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
requestId: 1234
trackingId: 56565
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36

please guide me what should i do.

Thanks In advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any HttpInterceptor implemented in your app which might be changing the HttpHeaders based on some logic